# Automating ffmpeg using Automator Service

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, video, automator

I often use **ffmpeg** off the command line to convert video files into *mp4* on my Mac (running Mavericks). Do note, however, that I am NOT re-encoding my videos; am just changing the container from an *avi* or an *mkv* to an *mp4*. The exact command I run on Terminal is as follows:

**/Users/Amit/Documents/Scripts/ffmpeg -i /input.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy /output.mp4**

As can be seen, this involves a lot of typing (for example, the entire path for ffmpeg and the source and target videos) and since I do a lot of such conversions, it would be great to have some Automator help here.

So, how can one go about creating a Finder Service that automates this activity? I would prefer a Finder Service instead of a standalone app or menu item.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Automator Service

You can use Automator to [create a new service or droplet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uhDG.png):

1. Launch Automator.app
2. Create a new service with service receives **files or folders** in **any application**
3. Add a **Run Shell Script** action
4. Set **Pass input:** to **as arguments**
5. Within the script, replace `echo` with the script below.
6. Save your workflow as a service.

### Shell Script

```
for f in "$@"
do
    /Users/Amit/Documents/Scripts/ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy -c:a copy "${f%.*}.mp4"
done
```

[image: Automator ffmpeg]

To learn more about using Automator, see Apple's [Mac Basics: Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did exactly as you suggest but it does nothing. I do have the service available on Finder as intended but when I select an mkv file and run the service, it does nothing. :(

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Just replaced "$fbname" with "${f%.*}.mp4" as suggested by Lauri Ranta. Damn, I wish I could accept both answers because both were equally helpful to my workaround!

Answer (score 6):

You could also add a function like this to a shell configuration file like `~/.bash_profile`:

```
mp4() {
  for f; do
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy "${f%.*}.mp4"
  done
}
```

Then you can just run `mp4 input.mkv`.

You can replace `/Users/Amit/Documents/Scripts/ffmpeg` with just `ffmpeg` if you move `ffmpeg` somewhere like `/usr/bin` or if you add `PATH=~/Documents/Scripts:$PATH` to `~/.bash_profile`.