# How to commit a file with TortoiseHg?

Tags: mac, finder, development

I have installed TortoiseHg on my Mac. I can run it, and it opens the repository browser. However, unlike on Windows, it doesn't add new items to Finder context menu. So I cannot right-click a file or a folder and do 'commit'. How can I perform commit then, without going to Terminal level?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you would need to do basically two things:

1. [Create an Automator Service that commits the job](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129929/automating-ffmpeg-using-automator-service)
2. [Add the Service to the context menu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294693/split-csv-file-using-automator-service-finder-context-menu)

Both of these topics has been answered here on Ask Different; I linked to two excellent examples.

What you would have to do is create an Applescript or a bash script (bash probably being easier) that "commits" whatever it is you want to commit - **you will have to scope the requirements in detail.**   Once you have the script written, add it to the context menu.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just learning to use Mac, and this looks really like the Mac way to do things! I really appreciate it. The disadvantage however is that AFAIU I wouldn't get a GUI window showing the changes in the files, and the list of changed files, and allowing me to enter the commit message and close a branch etc?..

Answer (score 1):

While @Allan's answer gives a nice explanation of how to add the commit command to the file context menu, what I was looking for was just a way to commit files without resorting to the command line. It turns out TortoiseHg has this functionality accessible in the main window, once you select the "Working Directory" revision and Commit mode (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>):

[image]